# Trying to select a row of data with MYSQL by using a foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to make a simple friend system with PHP & MYSQL and I don't know if it's even possible to get use data from another table with just their id. I am very new by the way so I don't know the language very well :) Any help would be very much valued

```
<?php if(count($friend_request) > 0): ?>
    <?php foreach ($friend_request as $friend_request): ?>
        <?php
            try{
                $statement = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$friend_request['id']' ");
                $user_info = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            }catch (PDOException $ex){
                $user_info = flashMessage("An error occurred: " .$ex->getMessage());
            }   

        ?>
        <?=$friend_request['id'] ?>
        <?=$friend_request['user_requested'] ?>
        <?=$friend_request['user_to'] ?>
        <?=$friend_request['request_date'] ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <center>
        <input id="emailInput" type="text" name="requestEmail" placeholder="someonesemail@bruh.com">
    </center>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You're not using `$user_info` anywhere.

Comment: Also the code looks to be prone to first SQL injections (direct) or second order SQL injections (stored) ones.

Comment: if `$friend_request` is the result of another query, you should just join the two queries instead of querying inside the loop.

Comment: yeah I know but im trying to get the $friend_request['id'] into the mysql query

Comment: If there is no HTML code between lines of PHP you dont need to use `<?php and ?>` on every line unless you like unreadable code

Comment: weird : `foreach ($friend_request as $friend_request)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use curly syntax if you want to put a quoted string in the index of a variable inside a string.

```
$statement = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '{$friend_request['id']}' ");
```

You can also leave the quotes out of the index, but that's not my preference.

But it would be better to use a prepared statement.

```
<?php
if(count($friend_request) > 0):
    $statement = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :id ");
    foreach ($friend_request as $friend_request):
        try{
            $statement->execute([':id' => $friend_request['id']]);
            $user_info = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            $user_info = flashMessage("An error occurred: " .$ex->getMessage());
        }   
        ?>
        <?=$friend_request['id'] ?>
        <?=$friend_request['user_requested'] ?>
        <?=$friend_request['user_to'] ?>
        <?=$friend_request['request_date'] ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <center>
        <input id="emailInput" type="text" name="requestEmail" placeholder="someonesemail@bruh.com">
    </center>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Or `$db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$friend_request[id]'");`

Comment: Yeah, I try to ignore that case, I consider it a weird anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your id is numeric, pass the value to a new var like `$id = friend_request['id'];` then your query can be 
`"SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1"`
without the " ' ", the "limit 1" is for performance, and the fetch you need to use just fetch [more info here](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) to retrieve just the row
`$statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`
later you can print or use the array $user_info for whatever you need it directly.

Comment: Here is digram that I just made, I hope this will help with what im trying to say?https://imgur.com/QV0WU8D

Comment: that is a simple join like ```SELECT a.username FROM users AS a LEFT JOIN friend_requests AS b ON b.user_id = a.id WHERE a.id = $id``` in the select part you can get any column you need with the a or b aliases and the field name :)